# How to combine ...if $x and a here-doc in perl?

Tags: perl, here-document

How is one supposed to write this?

```
print <<EOF; if $x
bla
EOF
```

I think it is called postfix notation, and a here-doc. I get a syntax error.

OK, I guess I'll just use

```
print "bla" if $x;
```

which, yes, does what I want.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? That the here-doc is only printed when `$x` is true?

Comment: OK, I added my goal. Thanks.

Comment: What you'd write, depends on what you want to do. If that conditional is supposed to be an independent statement, then you put the semicolon there in the middle. Same way as you'd do in `print "foo\n"; if (...) { ... }`. If it's supposed to be a postfix conditional, then it's part of the same statement, and you don't put the semicolon in there. Same way as in `print "foo\n" if ...`. There's nothing odd with the here-doc there, it's just a different-looking quote-like operator, same as `'...'` or `qw/.../`.

Comment: Well some of us couldn't figure it out for days. That's why I am posting this Q&A set. To help others.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
print <<EOF if $x;
bla
EOF
```

See https://github.com/Perl/perl5/pull/21978 .